# Will there be other .NET providers of Cloud Computing services?

Tags: .net, cloud, azure

Cloud computing is about providing computing, storage and networking capacities on demand. It is a fresh but very compelling concept for solving some specific tasks, for example:

- Running CPU heavy computations
- Having a scalable storage system for raw data
- Scaling realtime services up to the customer demand as it goes up and down.

I'm mainly working with Microsoft stack, which helps a lot in delivering complex enterprise applications. Yet, cloud computing offering for .NET is somewhat behind the market. Amd the only provider is Microsoft, any way (Windows Azure).

**Do you think there will be any diversity in .NET cloud providers** any time soon? **How many players**, do you think will be on the market, and **what could be the pricing** (considering that .NET could be run on Linux which should makes things a little cheaper )?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amazon's EC2 (Elastic Cloud Computing) service now supports Windows:
http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

On the same page you'll find pricing. Amazon is always trending towards lower and lower prices for it's services, so you should find them to be VERY competitive.

Here's another provider that provides cloud computing for the Microsoft Stack:
[Mosso](http://www.mosso.com)

Comment: You can rent entire (virtual) windows machines with Amazon

Comment: I am running several EC2 instances running Windows Server 2003 and ASP.NET web applications.

Comment: you can certainly rent but it won't scale automatically. Mosso, GAE and Windows Azure will take care of scaling, on Amazon EC2 you are pretty much on your own.

Answer (score 10):

A newcomer in this area is [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/).  Their tagline is 'Azure done right' (aka 'Heroku for ASP.NET')

Answer (score 3):

An important point to note is that EC2 was build on top of Amazon's existing infrastructure in order to extend that to outsiders. The important thing to note about this is that the instances are ephemeral -- meaning that *if there's a host failure you lose all data for that host*.

This isn't good or bad, but it's important to recognize that you will need to possibly compensate for this potential failover at some layer in your infrastructure stack.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand it that's limited to data storage. You'd still lose the host itself (ie. the OS). The infrastructure is designed such that you need to be able stand up additional hosts immediately in fail over situations.

Comment: I want to clarify that on AWS you can mount a share that is an S3 storage device.  That is, the default 150GB drive that you get with service image is ephemeral, but the S3 share is where you maintain your data.  S3 is backed up.  After I have configured a Windows server, I image that machine so I can spin up copies when needed.

With S3 you have a great ability to backup your data and as long as you plan you system configurations you can achieve a degree failover.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few competitors on the market though I suppose that depends on what you mean by cloud.

If you mean virtual servers, there are [GoGrid](http://www.gogrid.com/signUp/?template=ws08) and [SoftLayer](https://www.softlayer.com/cloudlayer.html). I would expect to see some consolidation among these "traditional" providers, and prices to drop over time. Amazon EC2 belongs in this category.

Another one is [Mosso](http://www.mosso.com/cloud.jsp), which virtualizes the application stack in a way that appears similar to Azure. You upload the app and don't know much about what it's running on. It claims to scale automatically like Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Azure is much more than a simple "cloud" provider, is an entire stack of technologies related, with specific options to manage them, so it cannot be compared to Mosso. Amazon EC2 is more similar, but it still do not have the full architecture design that Azure has.

When Azure was announced at PDC2008 the numbers behind it was something that will makes very difficult (if not impossible) for providers outside Microsoft to provide Azure compatible platforms (they were talking about tens of thousands of servers).

Said that I believe that a different (and easier to work with) "cloud" option for .Net could be created by competitor, for people not needing the whole MS offering or not willing to port their applications to Azure because of the architectural rework required.

A very nice scenario I would like would be to have a cloud offering made of Linux machine running Mono and the creation of a "Azure like" stack on Mono, open sourced, but it's just a dream.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like cloud computing could end up being a commodity best offered wherever electricity and taxes are cheapest, and there is decent security.  Seems like many larger ISPs could eventually position themselves as players.  If this happens there could later be a consolidation of them, although this could take 5-10 years to play out.

The cost will trend down based on clouds developed with non-proprietary operating systems, such as Linux, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there will be more providers of Windows/.NET based cloud computing services. Especially because the market for it is growing and all big players (IBM, Microsoft, Google, Amazone) are working on different solutions. In my opinion it is just a matter of time, that other companys will address this market. Currently there is some risk because Amazons EC2 images only work at amazon but that will change. I've talked to a CIO of a small company located in the Netherlands about the problem of 'being stuck to one vendor' and he told me that there is much effort spend by other companies to fullfill the requirements of the market.

Answer (score 0):

SalesForce.Com are also getting into the Cloud computing services mainly for CRM style of services but they do support numerous languages including .net.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GoGrid, [Appistry Cloud IQ](http://www.appistry.com) provides a cloud computing infrastructure that can be run on Amazon or in-house on your own hardware.  You can deploy .Net applications as well as Java and C apps.

Answer (score 0):

...just to add another answer WAY AFTER the question was answered, but AppHarbor is a great cloud provider for .NET, using Git as the deployment method.  It is hands down the simplist, fastest way to deploy a .NET app into the cloud.  It's pretty new at this time, but take a huge leap forward in getting .NET caught back up to the big players (i.e. AWS, Heroku, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used it myself yet, I came accross [DeployFu](http://www.deployfu.com/) which is very similar to AppHarbor (.NET apps with Git deployment, hosted on Amazon EC2).