# Is there a .Net Cloud Platform

Tags: .net, cloud, paas

What cloud providers are available for .Net apps?

Comment: https://appharbor.com/

Answer (score 24):

At [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) we're building Heroku for .NET (although we sometimes use the tagline "Azure done right"). That means we'll host your websites and assorted databases for you, in the cloud.

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft offers [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/?CR_CC=200002178&WT.srch=1&CR_SCC=200002178&WT.srch=1)

[Apprenda](http://apprenda.com/) also has a cloud platform offering.  It's a PaaS for any .NET app that can be downloaded and run anywhere - they don't host it.

Comment: thanks for the Apprenda mention. Note that Apprenda is not a cloud itself (in other words, Apprenda doesn't host it), it's a .NET application server and runtime that you can license and run on top of many of the other providers mentioned like EC2, GoGrid, etc. It gives your app a multi-tenant runtime, billing, usage metering, extensions to manage underlying infrastructure, and all you have to write is regular .NET code (ASP.NET web app, Silverlight, etc.) Apprenda + EC2 or GoGrid = your own cloud. (Full disclosure, I'm an Apprenda employee - but I think that allows me to provide clari

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://moncai.com/ - need to sign up for a beta invite, but it's basically Heroku for .NET

Comment: moncai uses mono which maybe an important thing to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [windows azure?](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Windows Azure Code Samples`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples).

> The Windows Azure platform is a
>   flexible cloud–computing platform that
>   lets you focus on solving business
>   problems and addressing customer
>   needs.

- [`Windows Azure Platform`](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)
- [`Windows Azure - Applications & Features`](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many cloud solutions that can run .NET apps. Azure is the Microsoft solution.

Others can be found here: [Will there be other .NET providers of Cloud Computing services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955012/will-there-be-other-net-providers-of-cloud-computing-services)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options, to name a few:

Amazon EC2: http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

Windows Azure: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/

GoGrid: http://www.gogrid.com/cloud-hosting/cloud-servers.php

Also, there are a large number of VPS (Virtual Private Servers) hosts which IMHO aren't all that different than what these bigger providers tout as "cloud", aside from needing to rent by the month instead of by the hour, which support a .NET environment.